# i need to remove (-,:,space,etc from my DateTime || Flutter ||

Tags: flutter, datetime

*'''*final Time = uniqueid + DateTime.now().toString() + DateTime.now().millisecond.toString();*'''*

and  get Time =uniqueid2022-01-24 16:42:03 .901280901
need Time =uniqueid20220124164203901280901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use this method to get exact result
first add plugin **intl**

```
flutter pub add intl
```

then import

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

then use this where you need the formatted date

```
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyyMMddkkmms');
final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
final Time = unique + formatted + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [replaceAll](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) function which replaces all substrings.

```
String finalTime = "uniqueid2022-01-24 16:42:03 .901280901";
String updatedFinalTime = finalTime.replaceAll("-","").replaceAll(":","").replaceAll(" ","");
```